# Does the capacity of the road influence how many agents can travel down it simultaneously?

Tags: simcity-2013

In SimCity each entity in the game world is called an 'agent', and each agent travels down roads seeking out other entities that require an agent of that particular type. An agent can be anything from the power from your power plant or a Sim travelling to work.

The screenshot below shows sewage:

[image]

I have two sewage structures next to each other at the bottom of a low density street and I'm being told that there is not enough capacity to deal with the current level of sewage, however if I bring up the information for the sewage structures, neither of them are operating at 100% capacity - so I'm wondering: does the capacity of the road influence how many agents can travel down it simultaneously?

Comment: I think limiting non-traffic related agents to road capacity would be bad design!! I really think it might be something else that might be affecting you! Though I have no clue what right now.

Comment: I noticed on watching many youtube videos of the beta, that many players were having power trouble when their power was located on the edge of the map - as though the power agents couldn't reach the far side of the map.  Perhaps the sewage pull is also limited in range (I notice your sewage is also located near the edge of the map.  Try splitting up the sewage processing and see if that sorts it out.

Comment: But splitting up the sewer processing means I have multiple regions of the map with high ground pollution, which in turn lowers land value across the map!

Comment: Does land value matter when the toilets are clogged?

Comment: What does your sewage data map look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does the capacity of the road influence how many agents can travel down it simultaneously?

[No](http://www.reddit.com/r/SimCity/comments/18yu29/does_road_density_affect_how_much_powerwater_it/c8jh9jp).  Number of lanes and whether there are stop signs or traffic lights only affect traffic agents.  They do not affect non-traffic agents.

- Traffic agents include police, fire, ambulance, garbage trucks, delivery trucks, moving trucks and of course sims driving their cars.
- Non-traffic agents include power, water, sewage and of course pedestrian sims.

Power and water agents are absorbed as they pass buildings with available capacity.  While the agents aren't affected by road capacity, they can be depleted by passing many buildings.  If you layout your city with a powerplant at position 1, it is unlikely that agents will reach buildings at position 2.

```
-----   -----
|   1   2   |
|           |
|           |
|           |
-------------
```

Update: There was a sewage issue fixed in [patch 1.8](http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/9388489.page).

> Fixed a clog in the pipes where sewage would sometimes get backed up
>   and act jittery.

Comment: `When there is a deficit, the building will pulse out a pull until it has absorbed the amount of sewage it can for that pull, at which point it will switch to a push!` -> So the problem was that both sewage plants were next to each other, and then second plant was at the end of the road. When the first place reached capacity it 'pushed' the remaining sewage away from the second plant...

Comment: @kalina that's as close to sense as I can make of it. You said that both were not at capacity, which seems to contradict it. Also, my two sewage processors were in a similar arrangement and did not block each other (they both went to 100%).